# OnListItemClick NullpointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, media-player, listitem

Hello I am currently getting error on some of my apps on android market :

This is the stacktrace :

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ****.****.MainActivity.onListItemClick(MainActivity.java:110)
    at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:870)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The code part where it goes wrong :

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        Sound s = (Sound) l.getItemAtPosition(position);
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

Mostly of the time it's working (playing sounds) but sometimes it gives a nullpointerexception and I don't know why maybe something with the MediaPlayer or super.onListItemClick() ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Probably s is null? Can you reproduce/debug?

could you provide the code of getItemAtPosition(position) of your list adapter implementation. and may wrap

```
    if (s != null) {
      mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, s.getSoundResourceId());
      mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
```

edit. hmm i was on the wrong line. you should wrap starting the media player with a null check because if you read the doc:

Returns

```
a MediaPlayer object, or null if creation failed
```

And then try to find out why creation fails.